"User did not provide appropriate variable bounds" error in BARON via AMPL
I'm trying to maximise a function with BARON. I have the following model file I am using via AMPL:
# Define the parameters
param len1;  # Length of the first index set
param len2;  # Length of the second index set

# Define the sets based on len1 and len2
set INDEX1 := 1..len1;
set INDEX2 := (len1+1)..(len1+len2);

# Define the coefficients parameter (indexed by 1..len1 + len2)
param coeffs{1..len1 + len2};
param coeffd{1..len1 + len2};

# Define the decision variables 
var x{1..2*(len1+len2)} >= 0.00001, <= 10;

# Define the objective function
maximize LogObjective:
    sum{i in 1..len1 + len2} coeffs[i] * log(x[i]) +
    sum{i in 1..len1 + len2} coeffd[i] * log((x[i + len1 + len2])**1) +
    sum{i in INDEX1, j in INDEX2} log((1 - (x[i] * x[j])) / (1 - (x[i] * x[j]) + (x[i + len1 + len2] * x[j + len1 + len2] * x[i] * x[j])));

# Add constraints to ensure 0 <= x[i] * x[j] < 1
subject to ProductConstraint1 {i in INDEX1, j in INDEX2}:
    x[i] * x[j] >= 0; 

subject to ProductConstraint2 {i in INDEX1, j in INDEX2}:
    x[i] * x[j] <= 1;  # Upper bound constraint
    
subject to ProductConstraint3 {i in INDEX1}:
    x[i + len1 + len2] >= 0;  # Upper bound constraint
    
subject to ProductConstraint4 {j in INDEX2}:
    x[j + len1 + len2] >= 0;  # Upper bound constraint

and when I run this in AMPL, it works and begins to optimise, giving me an answer, but I keep getting this error message I can't for the life of me get to go away:
===========================================================================
 This BARON run may utilize the following subsolver(s)
 For LP/MIP/QP: CLP/CBC                                         
 For NLP: IPOPT, FILTERSQP
===========================================================================
 Starting solution is feasible with a value of  -830.523          
 Doing local search
 Preprocessing found feasible solution with value -501.029
 Solving bounding LP
 Starting multi-start local search
 Done with local search
===========================================================================
  Iteration       Time (s)     Mem   Lower bound     Upper bound   Progress
          1           0.94    32MB    -501.029        infinity        NA
===========================================================================
 User did not provide appropriate variable bounds. 
 Some model expressions are unbounded.             
 We may not be able to guarantee globality.        
 Number of missing variable or expression bounds =    800
 Number of variable or expression bounds autoset =    800

Does anyone see a problem? There is also a data file that defines the parameters, but no variables are defined.

Is there anything bounding the denominator away from zero? Maybe that's what BARON is complaining about. I believe that sometimes, bounds on all the variables are not sufficient for BARON, and may be considered inappropriate if something in the model could be unbounded.

Ok thank you, having focused on the denominator, I can see I need x[i] * x[j] <=0.9999; and so on, as this otherwise allows a denominator of 0 when x[i] * x[j] <=1. That seems to have fixed it.

When you declare x to be nonnegative, all three families of >= 0 constraints are redundant and should just be omitted.

You need to bound the denominator away from zero, which the variable bounds you have provided do not accomplish. That is probably what BARON is complaining about.
Sometimes, bounds on all the variables are not sufficient for BARON, and may be considered inappropriate if something in the model could be unbounded.
